# JUnit, Android: What's a good level of detail in automated tests?

Tags: android, junit

I'm finding writing tests literally around 10 times more time consuming than writing the code itself. This question has been asked here: [Level of detail of your unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968014/level-of-detail-of-your-unit-tests) However, the answers all seemed pro-testing, and I'm not convinced.

I can appreciate how writing tests can save time, especially with all those bits of code which have caused me headaches in the past. However:

1. Annoyingly, it seems like the things most in need of automated testing are the hardest? (E.g. Testing for lack of GPS signal in Android)
2. Testing seems to need changes to the original code.
3. Test code adds dependencies And that's black box testing, let alone white box testing.
4. Under the assumption that I'll be the only person to deal with the code, and I'll only be developing relatively small apps, anything but the most important of tests on self contained code with a lot of logic is a waste of time?

Please share any information to help me write tests that ultimately save time and result in better code, I'm struggling to see the value at the moment!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing Test Driven Development?
If not (i.e. you are developing the code and adding the tests later) it doesn't make much sense.

It could be useful for regression testing if you refactor a lot or for integration testing if someone is using your APIs otherwise it could be a waste. In my experience maintaining the test cases burns a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing is very expensive.

It is useful if you plan to refactor your code deeply later on, for regression tests. Otherwise...

To test or not to test. That is the question.